# What happens if I seal my driveway on a cool day and then it rains?

Tags: driveway

What if I apply black jack 500 sealer and the temperature is between 40 and 50 degrees and it rains? We are selling a house and need to get this done right away,
The driveway has been power washed and cleaned.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. What do the product instructions say?

Comment: Not doing it due to bad weather is going to beat the heck out of doing it anyway and making a gooey mess of the driveway...take a cut on the price for not getting it done (negotiate with buyer.)

Answer (score 2):

From Blackjack 500 technical manual:

> **Temperatures must be 65°F and rising**, but below 90°F during application. Clean driveway with
>   Drive Kleen and thoroughly rinse. Remove puddles and then apply sealer to a slightly damp surface
>   (not wet). A small amount of water separation in the pail is normal, and should be easily
>   mixed in. Pour out 1/3 of the container and spread product across the blacktop surface with a
>   squeegee. Squeegee must be used to spread product and for proper application rates. After
>   application with squeegee, a follow up with a brush may be used if a textured surface is desired.
>   Complete the entire driveway in one continuous application to prevent “color shading”. If multiple
>   pails are used, it is best to match batch codes and blend the end of one pail into the beginning of
>   the other to maintain consistent coloring and texture. Do not over apply as this may lead to track- ing. **Do not apply if rain or cold temperatures are expected within 36 hours**

As implied by @Daniel Griscom, you really ought to read and follow the directions on the product container

Comment: Most of these products are an asphalt emulsion in water.  They setup in two phases, first the water dries out, allowing the oil products to mix, then the volatiles evaporate and the finish sets up.  If it starts raining, the product will get washed away before it sets.  And it will take longer to eventually dry and set.  Yes, a mess.